# How can I hide a style element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

ANSWERED: Thaks to @Traktor53 and @PHPglue

My webpage has a textarea for entering html code and one for entering css. The result is displayed in a div.

```
<textarea id="c" placeholder="CSS code here..." rows="10" cols="50">
 //What the user enters here will become a new <style> tag
</textarea>

<div id="pane">
//This is where it will be displayed
</div><br>
<button type="button" onclick="handleToggle()">Toggle</button>
```

I'm trying to use a javascript function that will toggle a specific style element on an off. I want to either delete the style tag and its contents or make it so the contents aren't being displayed.

EDIT: Here is my javascript

```
function handleToggle(){

        var pane = document.getElementById('pane');
        var css = document.getElementById('c');

        var x = document.getElementById('cssStyle');

        x.addClass("test");
```

This is how the style is created

```
function handleLaunch(){
        var div = document.getElementById('pane');
        var css = document.getElementById('c');

        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.id = "cssStyle"
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = document.getElementById('c').value;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)
```

Comment: What do you mean, style tags aren't visible ?

Comment: I don't want that style tag to be displayed. If that's not possible then I want to delete the style tag.

Comment: Confusing, you want a style tag, that is not displayed by default, to not be displayed? Do you mean you want a style tag, but the style shouldn't apply? If so, don't create a style tag?

Comment: How do I remove a style tag that has already been created using a javascript function?

Comment: Share your javascript...

Comment: `<style>` tags are already not visible.  You don't have to do anything to make them not visible.

Comment: I don't want the contents of the style tag to be displayed

Comment: `visibility: hidden` is CSS not HTML.

Comment: I think you can solve by manipulating `document.getElementById('pane').innerHTML`,  replacing symbols `<>` with html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, and viceversa to restore

Comment: @Marcos Perez Gude Can you give me an example? I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm in mobile, but tomorrow I can write an example for you, if nobody answer it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a style element with an id, for example using

```
// create STYLE element in javascript
var se =document.createElement("STYLE");
se.id = "myCSS"; // for example
se.innerText = "textarea { background-color: yellow"; // for example
document.body.appendChild(se);
```

And later remove the style element using standard DOM manipulation:

```
// remove existing element
document.getElementById( "myCSS").remove();
```

Alternatively you could update the content of a STYLE element previously created using *either javascript or  <script> tags*, as for example:

```
// change content of existing STYLE element:
document.getElementById( "myCSS").innerText = "textarea { background-color: blue";
```

---

Additional Information.

1. [`ChildNode.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) is part of the DOM4 recommendation and not supported in IE. The older syntax is to remove a DOM element as a child of its parent: `ChildNode.parentNode.removeChild( ChildNode);`
2. Although `InnerText` is widely supported and appears in the [DOM living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute), it is not supported in current W3C DOM standards which use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

Comment: Thank you! The remove() function did not work but I used .innerText = " " and it worked

Comment: @Sidward - dont forget to mark this answer as accepted. And please, don't edit new questions into the original one. Perhaps you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: The first person who responded was confused so I thought I needed to edit my OP to clarify

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden` is CSS not HTML. HTML attributes are assigned using`=`, not `:`. Many times these attributes are the same as CSS or JavaScript properties, but that's not the case here.

```
function removeLastStyleTag(){
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('style'), l = s.length;
  while(l--){
    var n = s[l];
    if(n.nodeName.match(/^style$/i)){
      n.parentNode.removeChild(n); l = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Is there a way I can do this only on a specific style tag instead of deleting all of them?

Comment: I should have stopped the loop. Fixed. It now just deletes the last style tag, wherever it is on the page.

Comment: That's not a 1 it's l, as in length. Just copy the code, instead of retyping it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the HTML Element to be hidden try the following in the CSS

```
.class{
    display: none;
}
```

**Edit**:

Seems like `addClass` and `removeClass` are not working everywhere. With standard JavaScript this can be achieved with

```
 function handleToggle(){
     // get the element
     var element = document.getElementById('pane');

     // toggle
     element.classList.toggle(".class");

 }
```

This will hide and show the element. It will not insert any code inside, if that's what you're looking for.

Hope this helps! If you have questions let me know

Comment: I'm getting the message "element.addClass is not a function" in the console

Comment: `addClass and removeClass` are functions of jQuery!

Comment: This is a poor quality answer. It's not focused on the problem in the main post, uses jQuery without telling it, doesn't solve the problem, and `element` is undefined. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: When I wrote some JavaScript today it worked, I was surprised, too. Try `element.classList += ".class"` to add the class. To delete the class, just clear it with `element.classList = ""` and then add all the classes you want to keep.

Comment: `.classList` is different from `.addClass`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude and @CMedina: I wrote **non jquery** JavaScript today (Theme for Textual IRC) where `addClass` and `removeClass` were working. I was surprised, too, but they worked. I'm sorry I was trying to help. Stack Overflow is trying hard to give me the feeling I should not, though.

Comment: @recursive which method would you suggest to add a class with pure JavaScript? Appending the classname to the classList will add the class.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude  `element` was of course a placeholder for any arbitrary HTML element... I thought that'd be clear.

Comment: The problem with your example is that. If you see the comment of Op, element is undefined, so he copied and pasted your example literally. I remove the downvote but I think this is not the answer for the problem on the question

Comment: Answers are not meant to be copied blindly. The Op didn't formulate his answer clearly. Since he talked about `visibility: hidden` not working I was assuming, that he is looking for the CSS to hide the element.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I changed element to a different variable name in case that was messing it up.

Comment: You must know that a style tag is not visible never.

Comment: @JHolub:  I recommend `element.classList.add(cls);`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank that was the one I was looking for! Very sorry!